# Linq Get history details by year on multiple tables

Tags: sql, database, linq, linq-to-entities

In my application I want to show the history details of a given user. A user can have many jobs and can access different promotions with different roles.

I want to be able to show this kind of history

**Year**	 	 	 	 **Position**
	 	 	 	 **Promotion**

2012	 	 	 	 Assistant
	 	 	 	 Promotion 2012

2013	 	 	 	 Manager
	 	 	 	 Promotion 2013

I tried this query (I am using Linq to entities)

```
var query = (from u in context.Users
             join j in context.Jobs.Where(jo => jo.JobStartDate.HasValue) on u.UserID equals j.UserID into jobs
             from job in jobs.DefaultIfEmpty()
             join uir in context.UserInRoles on u.UserID equals uir.UserID into userInRoles
             from userInRole in userInRoles.DefaultIfEmpty()
             join rip in context.RoleInPromotion on userInRole.RoleInPromotionID equals rip.RoleInPromotionID into roleInPromotions
             from roleInPromotion in roleInPromotions.DefaultIfEmpty()
             join p in context.Promotions.Where(pro => pro.PromotionStartDate.HasValue) on roleInPromotion.PromotionID equals p.PopulationTargetID into promotions
             from promo in promotions.DefaultIfEmpty()
             where u.UserID == userId 
             select new
             {
                 Year = job.JobStartDate.HasValue ? job.JobStartDate.Value.Year : promo.PromotionStartDate.HasValue ? promo.PromotionStartDate.Value.Year : 0,
                 JobTitle = job.JobTitle,
                 Promotion = promo.PromotionName
             }).Distinct().ToList();
```

But this is giving me this result, even though the user could not access any promotion back in 2012

**Year**	 	 	 	 **Position**
	 	 	 	 **Promotion**

2012	 	 	 	 Assistant
	 	 	 	 Promotion 2013

2013	 	 	 	 Manager
	 	 	 	 Promotion 2013

I tried this as well but it doesn't seem to change anything

```
group new { job, promo } by new { jobYear = job.JobStartDate.Value.Year, promoYear = promo.PromotionStartDate.Value.Year } into grp
```

Comment: I would design such a query in SQL and probably create a view or stored procedure and call that.

Answer (score 0):

have you try this:

```
var query = (from u in context.Users
             join j in context.Jobs.Where(jo => jo.JobStartDate.HasValue) on u.UserID equals j.UserID into jobs
             from job in jobs.DefaultIfEmpty()
             join uir in context.UserInRoles on u.UserID equals uir.UserID into userInRoles
             from userInRole in userInRoles.DefaultIfEmpty()
             join rip in context.RoleInPromotion on userInRole.RoleInPromotionID equals rip.RoleInPromotionID into roleInPromotions
             from roleInPromotion in roleInPromotions.DefaultIfEmpty()
             join p in context.Promotions.Where(pro => pro.PromotionStartDate.HasValue) on roleInPromotion.PromotionID equals p.PopulationTargetID into promotions
             from promo in promotions.DefaultIfEmpty()
             where u.UserID == userId 
         let year=job.JobStartDate.HasValue ? job.JobStartDate.Value.Year : promo.PromotionStartDate.HasValue ? promo.PromotionStartDate.Value.Year : 0
             select new
             {
                 Year =year ,
                 JobTitle = job.JobTitle,
                 Promotion = "Promotion "+year
             }).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Actually that won't help me because the promotion name does not always fallow that pattern "Promotion" + year. It has to be promo.PromotionName